# Error: error:1E08010C:DECODER routines::unsupported with Google auth library

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-storage, google-api-nodejs-client

I've recently ran into this error with the google cloud storage SDK on Node.js.
I know for a fact that this worked in the past without any changes, but I haven't touched the code in a while and might be wrong.

Here's the error itself:

```
Error: error:1E08010C:DECODER routines::unsupported
    at Sign.sign (node:internal/crypto/sig:131:29)
    at Object.sign (node_modules/jwa/index.js:152:45)
    at Object.jwsSign [as sign] (node_modules/jws/lib/sign-stream.js:32:24)
    at GoogleToken.requestToken (node_modules/gtoken/build/src/index.js:232:31)
    at GoogleToken.getTokenAsyncInner (node_modules/gtoken/build/src/index.js:166:21)
    at GoogleToken.getTokenAsync (node_modules/gtoken/build/src/index.js:145:55)
    at GoogleToken.getToken (node_modules/gtoken/build/src/index.js:97:21)
    at JWT.refreshTokenNoCache (node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/jwtclient.js:172:36)
    at JWT.refreshToken (node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:153:24)
    at JWT.getRequestMetadataAsync (node_modules/google-auth-library/build/src/auth/oauth2client.js:298:28) {
  library: 'DECODER routines',
  reason: 'unsupported',
  code: 'ERR_OSSL_UNSUPPORTED'
}
```

The code that throws this error is the following:

```js
const credentials = {
    type: process.env.TYPE,
    project_id: process.env.PROJECT_ID,
    private_key_id: process.env.PRIVATE_KEY_ID,
    private_key: process.env.PRIVATE_KEY,
    client_email: process.env.CLIENT_EMAIL,
    client_id: process.env.CLIENT_ID,
    auth_uri: process.env.AUTH_URI,
    token_uri: process.env.TOKEN_URI,
    auth_provider_x509_cert_url: process.env.AUTH_PROVIDER_X509_CERT_URL,
    client_x509_cert_url: process.env.CLIENT_X509_CERT_URL,
  };

  const storage = new Storage({
    credentials,
  });
  if (!req.file) {
    logger('POST /profile_image', logLevels.error, 'No file uploaded!');
    ResponseError.badRequest(res);
  }
  const bucketName = process.env.BUCKET_NAME;
  const bucket = storage.bucket(bucketName);
  const fileName = `profile_pics/${req.user}/${req.file.originalname}`;
  const file = bucket.file(fileName);
  const stream = file.createWriteStream({
    metadata: {
      contentType: req.file.mimetype,
    },
  });
  stream.on('error', (err) => {
    console.error('Error pushing the picture: ', err); <--- error
    throw err;
  });
  stream.on('finish', () => {
    return file.makePublic().then(async () => {
       ...
      })
  });
  stream.end(req.file.buffer);
```

The `process.env` contains all the right values, I've made sure to try with a new private key but same error. Has anyone seen this one before?

TIA!

Comment: 1) Do not store service accounts in environment variables. 2) If you do, do not break the service account into pieces. Base64 encode the entire service account, store it in a variable, and then Base64 decode it when required. 3) Your code is failing because the client is being set up with bad credentials. Most likely a corrupted private key.

Comment: Was the issue a corrupted private key?

Comment: I cannot say. I encoded as you advised me to and the problem seemed to have disappeared. I'm beginning to think that maybe the breaking down into pieces part may have corrupted the individual keys.

Comment: I am fairly confident you corrupted the **private_key** field based on the stack trace.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Answering this as community wiki. As mentioned above in comments by *John Hanley*

1. Do not store service accounts in environment variables.
2. If you do, do not break the service account into pieces. Base64 encode the entire service account, store it in a variable, and then Base64 decode it when required.
3. Your code is failing because the client is being set up with bad credentials. Most likely a corrupted private key.

Comment: informative, but not helpful

Comment: This is the way. See for example: https://github.com/orgs/vercel/discussions/219#discussioncomment-128702

Answer (score 59):

I got same issue and fixed it by replacing raw \n character with the newline character. Probably you get the key as raw data from your environment and \n character in the raw is not treated as a newline character. You can try this:

```
    private_key: process.env.PRIVATE_KEY.split(String.raw`\n`).join('\n'),
```

Comment: In local i was able to use the .env normally, but when i deployed to cloud run it failed.
This worked for me in local and in cloud run, but why this happend? Can you explain it to me please?

I tried to see what it does by printing it in console, but i cant see difference

Comment: I had to downgrade to node 16.16.0 and implement this: process.env.PRIVATE_KEY.split(String.raw`\n`).join('\n'), both changes were necessary in my case

Comment: or `.replace(/\\n/g, '\n')`

Answer (score 6):

I think you need to check the .env file and make sure you don't have any extra characters added to the private key for example a comma "," at the end.
that's the reason i was getting this error for me .

Comment: Yep, for me there was an extra apostrophe at the beginning of the key value.

Comment: You just saved me hours, I never would have spotted that.

Answer (score 5):

you can base64 encode the entire service account JSON and store it in an environment variable. Here's how you can adjust your code accordingly:

1. Base64 Encode the Service Account JSON using any online tools
   ex. https://www.base64encode.org/
2. Store the Base64-encoded String in Environment Variable

   `BASE64_ENCODED_SERVICE_ACCOUNT=your-base64-encoded-service-account`
3. Decode it in your code and use it like that

```
const base64EncodedServiceAccount = process.env.BASE64_ENCODED_SERVICE_ACCOUNT;
const decodedServiceAccount = Buffer.from(base64EncodedServiceAccount, 'base64').toString('utf-8');
const credentials = JSON.parse(decodedServiceAccount);
```

Comment: This solution worked for me, all the others failed 
for context I am using Nextjs other solution worked locally but not when deployed on Vercel except this one

Comment: Thanks for the solution.  I can see many answers who suggest updating the key using regex but that's not the right way.

Answer (score 2):

make both keys in `.env` to be one line only (the only way that worked for me)

```
PUBLIC_KEY="-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n<PUBLIC KEY>\n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"
PRIVATE_KEY="-----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY-----\n<PRIVATE KEY>\n-----END RSA PRIVATE KEY-----"
```

Answer (score 1):

The following was the only solution that worked for me

```
private_key: process.env.PRIVATE_KEY.replace(/\\n/gm, "\n"),
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have recently upgraded your openssl to version 3, you may have to enable legacy certs in the /etc/ssl/openssl.cnf file:

```
   openssl_conf = openssl_init
   
   [openssl_init]
   providers = provider_sect
   
   [provider_sect]
   default = default_sect
   legacy = legacy_sect
   
   [default_sect]
   activate = 1
   
   [legacy_sect]
   activate = 1
```

This information is from the [OpenSSL WIKI](https://wiki.openssl.org/index.php/OpenSSL_3.0#Providers)

Answer (score 0):

On your local env you should have it in on one line and with "":
`PUBLIC_KEY="-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n your key \n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----"`

And on deployed env you should have it without "":
`PUBLIC_KEY=-----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----\n your key \n-----END PUBLIC KEY-----`

Also, on public key variable put: `.replace(/\\n/g,"\n")`

This worked for me.